# I am getting a LookupError: unknown encoding: ascii when I run a py script converted to an exe via pyinstaller

Tags: python, text-files, pyinstaller

I am playing around with some code to try and run py script on Windows by converting it to an exe using pyinstaller.

I wrote this small python script that creates a txt file:

```
note = ("Hello World! \n\n\n" 
        "This is a testfile!")

with open("hello_world.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(note)
```

When I run the python script itself it works, but when I convert it to an exe via pyinstaller and run it I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "create_txt.py", line 7, in 
LookupError: unknown encoding: ascii

And this error points to this line:

```
with open("hello_world.txt", "w") as f:
```

Anyone who has an idea what can cause this?

Huge thanks, I've not been able to solve this one  myself and can't find much info on it either.

Cheers

Comment: how did you convert it to an exe using pyinstaller?

Comment: I copied your code, and converted it to exe using the following command "pyinstaller --onefile hello_world.py" and it worked

Comment: that isn't all of your code.